# Find StringDocument in Couchbase by its value

Tags: java, couchbase, nosql

I have StringDocuments in CouchBase, for example:
"a1": "bbb",
"a2": "ccc"

It's simple to find documents if you know its key ("a1" for instance), but I need to find document by its value. So I know just "bbb" and want to get the key "a1".
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: which version of Couchbase you are using ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to define a view ( a secondary index ). start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUVys2RUjMw

Answer (score 2):

You should understand the document ids are unique and the values are not unique so you can have 1000 documents with the same value. So what you should do is create a Map function which you can imagine as a index on a field.

So from couchbase admin ui add following Map function

```
function (doc, meta) {
   if(doc.content != null) {
       emit(doc.content,null);
   }  
}
```

and in your Java code

```
ViewQuery query = ViewQuery.from(DESIGN_DOCUMENT, THE_NAME_OF_UPPER_FUNCTION);
ViewResult result = bucket.query(query);
List<ViewRow> rows = result.allRows();
```